# Is it possible to edit a PS file in view mode in ISPF?

Tags: mainframe, ispf

We can edit a JCL file in ISPF when we open a file in edit mode. Is is possible to edit a file in view mode ?

Comment: What do you mean "view mode in JCL", are you talking about "ispf view" or some thing else or are you talking about view ???

Comment: yes Bruce, I am talking about ISPF view mode ...

Comment: So you are viewing a JCL file then ??

Comment: i want to edit and save it, in view mode only ...

Comment: Why not use edit in the first place ???, if you only have view available, there is probably a reason for that !!!

Comment: Does this have anything to do with JCL, or can I edit those references out?  It seems to be a fairly straighforward ISPF question.

Answer (score 6):

**View** is basically **Edit** with out the **save** command.

You can still use **Replace** command to over right a dataset/member with what you are editing (provided you have access and you are viewing an actual Dataset).
You may need to put c9999 in the line-number on the first line of the File.

Alternatively you could:

1. Use the **Cut** command (put c9999 in the line-number on the first line)
2. enter the **edit** command
3. delete the contents
4. do a paste
5. save and exit
6. exit view

Why not simply edit the JCL in the first place ???

Comment: thanks it works for me .... 
And I found a alternative also 'REPLACE .ZF .ZL(MEMBER_NAME)' ...

Comment: @Goyal So you should click on the Accept for this answer.